# Is there any reason you can't put a border around a <tr> in an html table using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, border, tablerow

I have a table and I have a tr with a class set to "underRow".

In CSS I have:

```
.underRow {
 border-bottom-color: #7a26b9;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

but the row  border doesn't seem to be changing at all.  If I move the class attribute down to the td's it works fine (but the issue is that I get a space in the middle where the padding is between the cells.  I want to avoid this space and have one straight line below the row.

Is there anything wrong with putting CSS border attributes on a row (tr) element?

Here is the rest of the CSS on this table for reference:

```
.quantityTable {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color: #d6b4E1;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #7a26b9;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: See the edit to my answer @ooo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No it should work.

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/qCzrg/

Perhaps you need to collapse your borders with

```
border-collapse:collapse
```

Or maybe other styles for the `TD` is overriding

Can you show some more code.

**As per your edit:**

> (but the issue is that i get a space in the middle where the padding
>   is between the cells. I want to avoid this space and have one straight
>   line below the row.

Sounds like you definitely need `border-collapse`

You should add it to the style of the `table`.

Here's a bit more about it: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/bordercollapse/

**EDIT 2**

Based on the new code and the following comment:

> the issue is that if i use: border-collapse:collapse then the
>   border-radius styling doesn't work anymore

I am guessing you want something like this

```
.quantityTable{
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    background-color: #d6b4E1;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 100%;    
}

.underRow{
    border-bottom-color: #7a26b9;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

.underRow:last-child{
    border-bottom:none;
}

.underRow td{
    padding: 15px;  
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/qCzrg/1/

**NOTE**

1. I made the radius bigger so you could see it easier.
2. I also removed the border from the table itself

Comment: the issue is that if i use: border-collapse:collapse then the border-radius styling doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Putting `border-collapse:collapse` on the table worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of some browsers don't take kindly to setting border styles on `tr` elements.

You can always set them on their `td`s instead.

```
.underRow td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #7a26b9;
}
```

If there is border spacing you may need to collapse your table borders using `border-collapse: collapse;`.

Comment: i updated the question a bit around the issue with using the class attribute on the tds.  Is there anyway around this so i have a straight line below the row.

Comment: Can I see the rest of your CSS for your table? As well as the table itself. Maybe put it on jsFiddle.

Comment: i updated the question with the rest of the css which is on the table.

Comment: the issue  now is that if i use: border-collapse:collapse then the border-radius styling doesn't work anymore